# Как в yii2 подгрузить часть формы по ajax с валидацией подгружаемых полей?

Tags: ajax, yii2, form, валидация, render

Ситуация:
есть общая форма, которая грузится и рендрится при первичной загрузке страницы. Через ActiveForm.

в процессе заполнения формы внутрь неё подгружатся по ajax еще некоторые поля, которые генерируются в отдельной вьюхе тоже через activeForm, только без тега , что бы не получилось ситуации когда форма в форме.

проблема в том, что подгружаемый кусок формы без валидации оказывается. Даже если грузить через renderAjax.

как добавить js валидацию?

Answer (score 0):

Если в фразе *подгружаемый кусок формы без валидации оказывается* вы подразумеваете ajax валидацию, то вам следует зарегистрировать ваши новые поля.

```
$('#form').yiiActiveForm.add({
    'id' : 'newfieldId1',
    'name' : 'newfieldName1',
    'value' : 'newfieldValue1',
});
```

Если не работает валидация не только на js, но и при сабмите, то смотрите правила в модели.

Могу еще предложить костыль: грузить форму полностью, но некоторые поля оставлять скрытыми, до определенного события.